# How to test console output code?

Tags: java, testing, printing, console

I have got some code, which display some scores in console. How can I test it? I need to store the output in file and than compare it? Another way how to test console output text?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Provide some related code and sample output to help others help you.  It sounds like you have reference output to which you might compare the output of a given run?

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing in Eclipse, by default it will display console output in the Console panel at the bottom of the IDE when you run your code - for example:

[image: Java Console Output in Eclipse]

Since it sounds like you have reference console output (i.e. a file that defines the console output you expect), yes, *you could* save the output of a run and compare it to the reference output as a test of the run's validity.

*However*, note that this approach to testing is far from ideal.  It is not automated & unit-focused.  Consider testing individual methods (or "units" of your code) with a unit-testing framework like [JUnit](http://junit.org/).